# Iframe mostra sistema em localhost - PHP

Tags: php, laravel, libcurl, iframe, file-get-contents

Bom dia

Vou tentar explicar a minha situação e ver se há solução.

Eu tenho um servidor que roda uma aplicação web em java que eu quero que funcione apenas em localhost.

Ainda, nesse servidor, eu tenho um sistema em PHP que está liberado para acesso pela internet, e que acessa essa aplicação java (localhost) e retorna o resultado. O porquê de estar utilizando outro sistema web, sendo que o java também é web, são por razões específicas.

Então, aqui vai o problema:

Eu quero acessar o sistema PHP, e dentro dele ter um iframe (exemplo) que me permite ter acesso ao sistema java que funciona só localhost. Deu pra entender?

Eu pensei em algo com cURL ou file_get_contend, mas talvez tenha outra forma ou uma biblioteca que ajude.

Agradeço desde já

Obrigado

Comment: Vamos por partes. O que quer dizer com acessar? Você pode usar um iframe, pelo que entendi. Não é necessário envolver o back até aí...

Comment: Boa noite. Eu quero que o iframe mostre a página do sistema java para eu mexer nele.
Só que como eu vou acessar de uma rede fora do localhost que estão os servidores, ele não irá funcionar com o simples iframe.
Tipo, eu estou na minha casa com o ip 201.198.099.x e o servidor PHP está com o ip 201.182,123.x. Ao acessar o servidor PHP, terá um iframe que mostrará o servidor web java, que está localhost como servidor PHP, para eu mudar as configurações do servidor java.

Comment: Não é possível fazer isso. É necessário que você utilize um IP fixo ou `NoIP` para ter acesso à seu computador através de um servidor.

Comment: Cara, desculpa mas ainda ta confuso para mim. Mas para resumir é o seguinte. Se você for no seu navegador e conseguir acessar uma página, seja lá qual for, você consegue jogar ela num iframe. Se não, então não tem jeito. Terá de rever sua arquitetura e sua demanda até